# JavaFX Canvas draw image with transparency

Tags: java, javafx

With a JavaFX Canvas, you can use `drawImage()`. However, is there anyway to draw the image with transparency (draw it with only 50% of opacity) or tint it with color?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Methods to Control Canvas Draw Operations**

There are methods to control the attributes of canvas drawing operations:

- [setGlobalAlpha()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setGlobalAlpha-double-) controls opacity.
- [setGlobalBlendMode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setGlobalBlendMode-javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode-) controls how items blend with items they are drawn over.
- [setEffect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setEffect-javafx.scene.effect.Effect-) sets the [effect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/Effect.html) to be applied after the next draw call.

**Sample Usage**

[image: batsignal]

The source image used by the program is:

[image: bat signal]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CanvasEffects extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC);

        final int NUM_IMGS = 5;
        final double W = image.getWidth();
        final double H = image.getHeight();

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W * NUM_IMGS, H);
        final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.GOLD);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        gc.setGlobalBlendMode(BlendMode.SCREEN);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_IMGS; i++) {
            final double opacity = 1 - ((double) i) / NUM_IMGS;
            System.out.println(opacity);
            gc.setGlobalAlpha(opacity);
            gc.setEffect(new BoxBlur(i * 2, i * 2, 3));

            gc.drawImage(image, i * W, 0);
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(canvas)));
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // icon license: Linkware (Backlink to http://uiconstock.com required) commercial usage not allowed.
    private static final String IMAGE_LOC = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/flat-halloween/128/Halloween-Bat-icon.png";
}
```

Comment: Do you know where can I find a list of all these `Effect` subclasses? Also thank you!

Comment: In the [javafx.scene.effect javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/package-summary.html)

Comment: @Voldemort In Eclipse, place the cursor on the Effect class name and press F4 to view the type hierarchy.

Comment: bug fix >>> final double h = image.getHeight();

Comment: Thx d33j, I fixed the bug you referenced in the sample code.