# Draw FontIcon (Ikonli) directly inside "javafx.scene.Canvas"

Tags: javafx

How to draw FontIcon (Ikonli) directly in "javafx.scene.Canvas" version kordamp 12.3.1  https://github.com/kordamp/ikonli

The right side contains the Canvas that the icon on the left side should appear.
I think there must be another way to do this, perhaps getting the svg, but still using Ikonli I'm not finding how to do this

[Image Ikonli canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtYjf.png)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
 
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
 
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeSolid;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;
 

public class IkonliCanvas extends Application {
   
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Criar um Canvas
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100, 400 );
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();        
        
        Pane pcanvas = new Pane();
        pcanvas.getChildren().add(canvas); 
        
        FontIcon fi = new FontIcon(FontAwesomeSolid.APPLE_ALT);      
        fi.setIconSize(30);
    
        Image snapshot = fi.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);       
        gc.drawImage(snapshot, 40,100);
        
        
        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.getChildren().add(fi);
        p.setPrefWidth(100);        
        fi.setLayoutX(40);
        fi.setLayoutY(100); 
        
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setLeft(p);
        bp.setCenter(pcanvas);
             
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 220,400);
    
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Canvas Ikonli");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

This way the result is not displayed correctly

Comment: By kordamp, I think you mean [ikonli](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/).  But what does "the result is not displayed correctly" mean?  Can you provide an image of what you have and what you expect?  Why display the icon on a canvas instead of the scene graph?  You can update your question to clarify.

Comment: It's Ikonli from the kordamp.org implementation
The reason for using Canvas is performance. It is a necessity for the new version of the program. In the old version everything works, without using Canvas

Comment: Snapshotting a node and then repainting it does not really sound like it would improve performance. But, if this is the way you want to go, create and post a [mre], and (to reiterate another comment) be specific about "not displayed correctly".

Comment: It's not just the design of the icon using Canvas, there are many graphics within Canvas that make the solution much faster than creating many Nodes, maintaining these many Nodes makes JavaFX slow, in fact I already posted this to the JavaFX team, they recognized the problem and did not set a date for improving performance

Comment: Please post a [mre], as requested. This works just fine for me.

Comment: Your `FontIcon` is not added to a scene. See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)). This should work if you move the `fi.snapshot(...)` to after `Scene scene = new Scene(...)`.

Comment: If you're displaying lots of `FontIcon`s in the canvas, the process of adding them all to a scene and then snapshotting them is likely to be just as expensive as putting them in a scene graph. This, of course, depends on your use case. It *might* be more performant, e.g., to use the swing packages to get a raster from an `ImageIcon`, which you can then use directly as a buffer in a JavaFX `WriteableImage` (which you can draw on the canvas). That will obviously be a lot more complex.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100060/javafx-canvas-draw-image-with-transparency) can help.

Comment: You don't need to use Ikonli to use fonts.  You can use otf or ttf or web fonts in JavaFX (many, if not all fonts supported by Ikonli will be available in such formats), set the appropriate font on the canvas graphics context and render the font symbols as text using graphics context APIs.

Comment: Most fonts are also available as svg images which (might) be able to be converted svg paths which you can render to the canvas using third party tools, though that would likely be quite a bit of work and cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, I don't know Ikonli, I thought about getting his svg and drawing directly on the canvas.  The problem is in Ikonli, in other images it works fine

Comment: Implemented the suggestion from @jewelsea to use the Ikonli ttf instead of snapshotting an icon as an addition to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code displays incorrectly is that you are taking a snapshot of a node that is not part of a scene.

As stated in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)), a `Node` must be part of a scene in order for the snapshot to work correctly.

(Specifically, what is happening is that under the hood the `FontIcon` class sets a CSS style which references a font that is included as part of the Ikonli icon pack. CSS is not applied to nodes that are not part of a scene, so the icon is being snapshot while not having the correct font set to it.)

Note the scene containing the node does not actually have to be rendered, so you can just add the `Text` node to a scene, snapshot it to retrieve an image, and then remove it. As long as you organize this in a reasonable way, it may be performant enough for what you're doing. Here's a quick example with a reasonable amount of effort invested in performance:

First a cache to hold the generated images:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikon;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ImageCache {

    private final Pane dummyPane = new Pane();
    private final Scene dummyScene = new Scene(dummyPane);

    private static final int ICON_SIZE = 30;

    private final Map<Ikon, Image> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public Image getImage(Ikon icon) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(icon, this::createImage);
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    private Image createImage(Ikon icon) {
        FontIcon fontIcon = new FontIcon(icon);
        fontIcon.setIconSize(ICON_SIZE);
        dummyPane.getChildren().add(fontIcon);
        Image img = fontIcon.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        dummyPane.getChildren().remove(fontIcon);
        return img;
    }
}
```

Note here that the `dummyPane` only ever contains one `Node`, only one `FontIcon` instance is ever created for any given icon you use, and that `FontIcon` instance is eligible for garbage collection immediately after the corresponding image is created.

And then you can use this in the following way:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeSolid;


public class IkonliCanvas extends Application {

    private final ImageCache imageCache = new ImageCache();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Criar um Canvas
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100, 400 );
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Pane pcanvas = new Pane();
        pcanvas.getChildren().add(canvas);

        gc.drawImage(imageCache.getImage(FontAwesomeSolid.APPLE_ALT), 40,100);


        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(pcanvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 220,400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Canvas Ikonli");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

---

However, taking a snapshot of a `Text` node is not an efficient way to draw to a canvas in general. A `Text` node (`FontIcon` is a subclass of `Text`) just displays text and a canvas already has a built-in mechanism for displaying text via `getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(...)`. As mentioned by @jewelsea in his comments, Ikonli fonts are available for the icons, and a (likely) more efficient approach is just to set the font and draw the appropriate text on the canvas.

Indeed, reading the [Ikonli documentation](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/#_authoring), you can see that an Ikonli `Ikon` instance contains a description and character code, and that an icon pack includes a ttf font defintion file.

To determine the name of the font resource, just look it up from the ikon handler, and to determine the character code for the icon, just call `getCode()`. `IkonHandler`s are provided as service providers and there is an `IkonResolver` class that can find the `IkonHandler` given an icon's description.

The following implements this approach:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikon;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeSolid;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver;

import java.net.URL;

public class IkonliTextToCanvas extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Ikon icon = FontAwesomeSolid.APPLE_ALT;

        IkonHandler handler = IkonResolver.getInstance().resolve(icon.getDescription());
        URL fontResource = handler.getFontResource();
        Font fa5Solid  = Font.loadFont(fontResource.toExternalForm(), 30);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100 ,400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFont(fa5Solid);
        String text = Character.toString(icon.getCode());
        gc.fillText(text, 40, 100);

        Pane root = new Pane(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 220, 400, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This gives the same result:

[image]

For completeness, here are the `module-info.java`

```
module org.jamesd.examples.ikonli {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5;
    exports org.jamesd.examples.ikonli;
}
```

and a minimal `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jamesd.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ikonli</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome-pack</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome5-pack</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The last code example should work out of the box if you modify the `pom.xml` and the module descriptor to include other Ikonli icon packs.